# How space itemize

Tags: beamer

How to set space between each items to 2ex, between subitems to 1ex, between an item and its subitem to 1ex, between a subitem and the next item to 2ex?

I've tried to proceed this way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \topsep    1ex
              \parsep    0\p@   \@plus\p@
              \itemsep   \parsep}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Here are two interesting things:
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Here are two interesting things:
                \item Here are two interesting things:
            \end{itemize}
                \item Here are two interesting things:
                \item Here are two interesting things:
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `enumitem` package could help.

Comment: @Manuel unfortunately, the `enumitem` package and `beamer` don't cooperate well.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I supposed so, but I tried :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option redefining `\itemize` (as defined in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`) to conditionally set `\itemsep` based on the value of `\@itemdepth` (the new code is signaled by `% start change`, `% end change`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
\advance\@itemdepth\@ne
\beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
\usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
\usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
\list
  {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
  {\def\makelabel##1{%
  {%
\hss\llap{{%
\usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
  }%
}%
% start change
\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
\setlength\itemsep{2ex}
\else
\ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
\setlength\itemsep{1ex}
\fi\fi%
% end change
  }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here are two interesting things:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Here are two interesting things:
  \item Here are two interesting things:
  \item Here are two interesting things:
  \end{itemize}
\item Here are two interesting things:
\item Here are two interesting things:
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of `xpatch` we can patch `\itemize` and the code simplifies a little:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\ifnum\@itemdepth=1\relax
     \setlength\itemsep{2ex}
   \else
     \ifnum\@itemdepth=2\relax
   \setlength\itemsep{1ex}
   \fi\fi\def\makelabel
  }
 {}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here are two interesting things:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Here are two interesting things:
  \item Here are two interesting things:
  \item Here are two interesting things:
  \end{itemize}
\item Here are two interesting things:
\item Here are two interesting things:
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```