# Spacing between bullet points

Tags: beamer, itemize, report, bullets

How to customize the spacing between two items within `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}`, without every time putting for eg. say,  `\vspace{3mm}` ?
Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176963/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16793/134144

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is as follows, if you are thinking of a single list (else change itemsep globally):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

% default
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Customize}
{
\newlength\savlength
\setlength{\savlength}{\itemsep}

\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{10mm}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item

\item fourth item
\setlength{\itemsep}{0.mm}
\item fifth item
\item sixth item
\end{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{\savlength}
}

\textbf{Default}

% default
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you